# Is it possible to join elements of an Akka Streams Source?

Tags: akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams

If I have a source like his :

```
val source = Source(List("hell", "o\n my ", "name is bob"))
```

Is it possible to join and re-split elements on a specific separator pattern, for example on the '\n' character to have something like this as a result? :

```
Source(List("hello", "my name is bob"))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using Framing :

```
source.via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 100, allowTruncation = true))
```